# How to detect if its a conference call on twilio?

Tags: twilio, call, conference

I have an app working with twilio. If some user calls the twilio number which i'm using in my app, ı want to check if it is a conference call or not.

If a conference call comes in i want to record voice. Can anybody help?

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough information to answer. Please provide more details.

Comment: Can you share your code?